# AddHour / AddMinute store within a ListItem

Tags: c#, list, while-loop

I am using c#.net

I have two times pulled from a database (‘earliest start time’ and ‘latest end time’).

I want to loop through and add ‘in-between’ times to a list.

Example

- earliest start time – 12:00
- 12:30
- 13:00
- 13:30
- 14:00
- 14:30
- latest end time – 15:00

I have found some code, but as the information is being pulled from a database the start time could be 12:00/12:30 etc. I don’t know how to adapt the below code to expect both times (full hour / half an hour)

```
int i = -1; 

List<string> appointmentTimes = new List<string>();

while (DateTime.Today.AddHours(firstTime).AddMinutes(i * 30).Hour < lastTime)
{
appointmentTimes.Add(DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(30*(++i)); );
}
```

Would I have to split the firstTime into hours/mintues?

Example

```
while (DateTime.Today.AddHours(firstTimeHour).AddMinutes(firstTimeMintues, i * 30).Hour < lastTime)
{
appointmentTimes.Add(DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(30*(++i)); );
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Justin for putting me on the right track.

```
            // ---- Create a new list
            List<string> appointmentTimes = new List<string>();

            // ---- If information is pulled back
            if (myResults != null)
            {
                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

                DateTime FirstTime = Convert.ToDateTime(myResult.firstStart);
                DateTime LatestTime = Convert.ToDateTime(myResult.lastEnd);

                while (FirstTime < LatestTime )
                {
                    appTimes.Add(FirstTime .ToString());
                    FirstTime += time;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just a hint rather than an answer but it will probably be easier to use TimeSpan to loop through the available times.

Use TimeSpan.FromHours and TimeSpan.FromMinutes to get a TimeSpan and then increment 30 to it adding to the list similar to how you're doing is with TimeSpan.Hours and TimeSpan.Minutes.